# "strong stationary process" equivalent to a process with "indentically distributed" random variables?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I want to know if a strong stationary process is equivalent to a process with identically distributed RVs.

In another words : if A is the set of s.s.s processes and B is the set of processes with identically distributed RVs, is it true that A = B ?

Comment: What do you mean by an "identically distributed process"? That $X_1,X_2,\dots$ all have the same distribution?

Comment: Yes they have the same distribution

Comment: If I am not mistaken i.i.d processes are a subset of s.s.s processes set. I wanted to know what is the processes other than i.i.d ones that forms the set of s.s.s processes

Comment: I was thinking that since the s.s.s processes are characterised by random variables that have the same CDFs, then these random variables are identically distributed.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same. In a strong stationary process $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ it is the case that all of the $X_n$'s have the same distribution. However, the converse does not hold.

To see why, take $X_2,X_3,\dots$ to be IID (whatever distribution you like, but not constant), and $X_1=X_2$. Then all of these terms are identically distributed, but this is not a strong stationary sequences because, for instance, $(X_1,X_2)$ is not equal in distribution to $(X_2,X_3)$.

Comment: Thanks this is clear. Can you give me an example of a strong stationary process that is not an IID process ?

Comment: I think it should work to take $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, and define $X_n = X_1$ if $n$ is odd, and $X_n=-X_1$ if $n$ is even. This should be a strong stationary process, but it's not IID.

Comment: Do you mean an i.i.d. random process is _not_ a strict stationary random process? And what do you mean by "(X1, X2) is not equal in distribution to (X2, X3)"? Why aren't they equal even if all Xs have identical probability density/mass functions?

Comment: @starriet No, an IID process *is* a strong stationary process. For your second question, $\mathbb{P}(X_1=X_2)=1$ while $\mathbb{P}(X_2=X_3)<1$ since $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent and not constant.

Comment: So, any "strong(strict) stationary process" _is_ an "identically distributed" process, but not vice versa, right? (The first paragraph of the answer is a little bit confusing) Thanks! :)

Comment: @starriet Yes, every strong stationary process is a sequence of identically distributed RVs, but not every sequence of identically distributed RVs is a stationary process. If you add the condition that the sequence is *independent* (so an IID process), then it is a stationary process. But not every stationary process is an IID process.